# Hiding zoned buildings only

Tags: simcity-4

It it possible, or is there a mod, that allows you to hide zoned buildings only. This used to be a an option in Simcity 3000, which was great for adding/finding subways, busstops and other government buildings/parks.

I have searched high and low but all I can find was "No", but maybe someone knows a trick or mod?

*FYI: I know about the zone view using the dataview, but this hides all structures...*

Comment: I wondered this myself for a long time, but stopped playing simcity 4. Else I'da asked it myself.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to hide the zoned buildings.  Instead, you can use the dataviews to find the buildings you want.  This includes:

- Traffic : (note there are bus and train subviews)
- Police
- Fire
- Education
- Health
- Power
- Water
- Garbage

Comment: Yep, the dataviews. It still doesn't just show whatever you want. If only it would highlight every busstop, or subway, like it does with the other dataviews...

Comment: Viewing traffic by volume, then selecting "bus" or "subway", can help with that. But definitely would be nice to get even finer detail.